# Style table in CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I want to make a table with no header, 2 column, the first cell of the first row spans 65% width of the table and from the second row, the first cell spans 20% width of the table.

Here are the CSS selector of 2 kinds of first column:

```
 #myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)

 #myTable > tbody > tr:not(:first-child) > td:nth-child(1)
```

How can I make it?

Edit: Here is my solution and it didn't work

```
table, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
   } 

   #myTable { 
       border-collapse: collapse; 
       width: 80%; 
       table-layout: fixed; 
   } 

   #myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) { 
       width: 70%; 
       height: 100; 
   } 

   #myTable > tbody > tr:not(:first-child) > td:nth-child(1) { 
       width: 20%; 
   }
```

Comment: could you show us what have you tried ( in terms of code )?

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of grids, very straightforward:

```
.myTable {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.myTable first-row {
  grid-template-columns: 65px 35px;      
}

.myTable second-row {
  grid-template-columns: 20px 80px;
}
```

Comment: I want it has a relative value with table width

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use classes for cells you want to style. Because any changes and your style will be broken.

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

.flexCell {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.firstCell {
  width: 65%;
}

.secondCell {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="firstCell">
            Column one
          </td>
          <td class="flexCell">
            Column two
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="secondCell">
            Column one (second row)
          </td>
          <td class="flexCell">
            Column two (second row)
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used flex-grow to make other two cell fill the rest of the table.